# how to send 300 or more images from iphone to watchapp Extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, watchos-2

I wants to send number of images(300 aprox) from iPhone to watch.and  downloads all images and compress it,then i convert all images to nsdata then send towards watch using a dictionary.but i am getting too much time.
please suggest me for good way for send multiple images from iPhone to watch.

I am using "session transferUserInfo:arrDictImg" method for send images data.

Answer (score 2):

you cant control time between iPhone and the watch. It is a known issue because of bluetooth.
However try to reduce the size of the images not by compression but by lowering the quality to 0.1 of the original image (I assume you don't want them HD since the watch screen is small). This will reduce the time dramatically (around 90%)!

Happy Coding!